# Karma "request.replace is not a function" error

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, webpack-2, karma-webpack

I am using Karma 1.5.0, Webpack 2.3.2 and Karma-Webpack 2.0.3.

When I build my project (meaning no Karma) it builds with Webpack fine.  But when I try to run my Karma tests I get the following error:

> TypeError: request.replace is not a function

From what I have seen on the web, this is a Webpack error that is thrown when more than one entry point is used.  The only "fix" I can see is to use only one entry point.  But Karma-Webpack sets up the entry points (one for each test).

**So I am confused. How do others get this to work?**

Here are links to my config files in case they are relevant:

[wepack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/390b5e9c19c4f314baf32c2d07e032c2#file-webpack-config-js) - [yarn.lock](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/390b5e9c19c4f314baf32c2d07e032c2#file-yarn-lock) - [karma.config.js](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/390b5e9c19c4f314baf32c2d07e032c2#file-karma-conf-js) - [package.json](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/390b5e9c19c4f314baf32c2d07e032c2#file-package-json)

Comment: Ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

@Vaccano I hit this exact same error today. For me it was the inclusion of `AureliaPlugin()` when I had no `entry:` specified in the webpack config. See [this bug](https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/issues/134) report. Although I notice that you have an `entry:` defined. Maybe try commenting out the other plugins and the ctor you have defined for `AureliaPlugin()` see what happends then ?